# Jsoup, parse html table

Tags: java, web-scraping, html-table, jsoup

This is probably dumb question, but I can't really figure it out. I'm trying to parse html output from page: http://meteo.uwb.edu.pl/

So basically I need to extract values from table, from left side (blue text) as keys(headers) and from right side (brown text) as values. Additionaly, header labels ("Aktualna pogoda/Weather conditions: ")

My intention is to get html table from html output and then parse its row, but I can't figure it out, because html output is rather complicated. I'm starting from it:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://meteo.uwb.edu.pl/").get();
Elements tables = doc.select("table");
for (Element row : table.select("tr"))
{
  Elements tds = row.select("td:not([rowspan])");
  System.out.println(tds.get(0).text() + "->" + tds.get(1).text());
}
```

But still my result is a mess. Do you have any ideas how to parse it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keys data from first table can be retrieved by this code:

```
doc.select("table").get(1).select("tbody").get(1).select("tr").get(1).select("td").get(0).select("b")
```

and value by this:

```
doc.select("table").get(1).select("tbody").get(1).select("tr").get(1).select("td").get(1).select("b")
```

**for second table**

```
doc.select("table").get(2).select("tbody").get(0).select("tr").get(1).select("td").get(0).select("b")
```

and

```
doc.select("table").get(2).select("tbody").get(0).select("tr").get(1).select("td").get(1).select("b")
```

Comment: Thanks, your soultion looks far better than mine, I will check it

Answer (score 0):

I managed it this way:

```
 doc = Jsoup.connect("http://meteo.uwb.edu.pl/").get();
 Elements tables = doc.select("td");
 Elements headers = tables.get(2).select("b");
 Elements vals = tables.get(3).select("b");
 Map all = new HashMap();

 for (int i=0;i<headers.size() ; i++) all.put(headers.get(i).text(),vals.get(i).text());
```

It seems to be ok.